# Hand wave-y "derivation" of relativistic momentum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, energy, momentum

In lecture, my professor went over a kind of non-rigorous "derivation" (not really a derivation, but more of a demonstration) of the expression for relativistic momentum. However, I don't quite understand a specific idea in it that seems to be really important. Here's the demonstration (note: $P =$ power, $E =$ energy (time-dependent), $p =$ momentum)

$$P = \frac{\partial E}{\partial t} = \vec{F} \cdot \vec{v} = \frac{\partial \vec{p}}{\partial t} \cdot \frac{\partial \vec{x}}{\partial t}$$
$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{(\partial t)^2}(\partial \vec{p} \cdot \partial \vec{x})$$
$$\partial E = \frac{1}{\partial t}(\partial \vec{p} \cdot \partial \vec{x}) = \partial \vec{p} \cdot \frac{\partial \vec{x}}{\partial t}$$
assuming unidirectionality:
$$\partial E = \partial p \frac{\partial x}{\partial t};\quad \frac{\partial E}{\partial p} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\label{Equation A}\tag{Equation A}$$
using
$$\vec{p} = \bar{h}\vec{k},\quad E = \bar{h}\omega,$$
$(\vec{k},\omega)$ form a 4-vector for which we can write the lorentz invariant equation:
$$(pc)^2 - E^2 = L^2,$$
where $pc$ is spacelike and $E$ is timelike differentiating above equation wrt $p$:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial p} ((pc)^2 - E^2 = L) = 2c^2p - 2E \frac{\partial E}{\partial p} = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial p} = \frac{pc^2}{E}\label{Equation B}\tag{Equation B}$$
Combining ($\ref{Equation A}$) and ($\ref{Equation B}$):
$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial p} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} = v = \frac{pc^2}{E}$$
$$\left(\frac{v^2}{c^2} - 1\right)E^2 = -L^2$$
lorentz invariant from above
$$E = \gamma L$$
($\gamma = $ lorentz factor).

He then told us that $L = m_0c^2$, and then claimed that this means $E = \gamma m_0c^2$, and that this leads to the conclusion that $p = \gamma m_0v$.

Here is what I don't get about this:

1. Why is $(pc)^2 - E^2 = L^2$ a lorentz invariant? The only lorentz invariant equation we've been taught in class so far is $(\Delta r)^2 - (c\Delta t)^2 = L^2$
2. How does he go from $\frac{\partial E}{\partial p} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} = v = \frac{pc^2}{E}$ to $(\frac{v^2}{c^2}-1)E = -L$
3. How does $E = \gamma m_0 c^2$ lead to the conclusion that $p = \gamma m_0 v$?

While answering all 3 of these questions would be greatly appreciated, my biggest concern is understanding question 2 and 3.

Thank you so much in advance if you respond!

Comment: You should endeavor to only ask a single question at a time.

Comment: @MattHanson why needlessly clutter the physics stack exchange with 3 separate questions with identical setups

Comment: Your professor actually dragged Planck’s constant into this? If you know what four-vectors are, I don’t understand why he/she doesn’t construct the energy-momentum four-vector as $p^\mu=m\,dx^\mu/d\tau$.

Comment: @Ghoster yeah...we haven't been formally introduced to it in college before he did this demonstration, but I don't mind since I saw it at some point in high school. I'm comfortable enough with it

Comment: Why not ignore him/her and read your textbook instead?

Comment: Relativity stands fine on its own without quantum mechanics.

Comment: Writing things like $\partial E = \frac{1}{\partial t}(\partial \vec{p} \cdot \partial \vec{x})$ is… questionable.

Comment: @Ghoster keep in mind we're only 2nd year university students, so our prof is doing the best he can with math that we'll understand.

Comment: Actually, your prof is making this far more *complicated* than it needs to be. Frankly, I am appalled by this derivation.

Answer (score 1):

In my reply, I'll use $(,,,,m)$ for your $\left(\vec{x},\vec{p},\vec{v},\vec{F},m_0\right)$. I'll also be using coordinate differentials $(dt,d)$ in place of differences $(Δt,Δ)$.

Let's clean this up a little, and do this in a more consistent (and robust) fashion. I'll try to touch on your key talking points, though the stream of consciousness your prof. used in question #2 needs to be replaced, as others replying to you have noted. I'll also show how it's all connected to the corresponding non-relativistic versions to aid in intuiting everything. There's a surprise in store at the end - somewhat like Marty [pulling a Jimmy Hendrix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T_WSXXPQYeY), a half-decade ahead of its time, in the middle of a performance of Johnny B. Goode. **Edit:** More like a decade and a half, since the guitar action was set in the mid-1950's.

First, it's easier to deal with the infinitesimal forms of the Lorentz transformation, since they are linear, while their corresponding finite forms, being non-linear, are more complicated and don't convey anything more. Corresponding to the finite Lorentz transform
$$dt → γ\left(dt - \frac{v dx}{c^2}\right),\quad dx → γ\left(dx - v dt\right),\quad dy → dy,\quad dz → dz\quad\left(γ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - (v/c)^2}}\right)$$
is the infinitesimal form
$$δ(dt) = -\frac{υ dx}{c^2},\quad δ(dx) = -υ dt,\quad δ(dy) = 0,\quad δ(dz) = 0,$$
where $υ$ is the infinitesimal form of $v$. More generally, under an infinitesimal Lorentz transformation, where $$ is taken in an arbitrary direction, you have the following:$$δ(dt) = -\frac{·d}{c^2},\quad δ(d) = - dt.$$
That's what makes the infinitesimal version easier. Besides it being linear, you can generalize to arbitrary directions without the awkward "$x$ and everything else" decompositions.

From the transform follows
$$δ\frac{|d|^2 - c^2|dt|^2}2 = d·δ(d) - c^2 dt δ(dt) = 0.$$
Thus: the first Lorentz invariant that you described:
$$|d|^2 - c^2|dt|^2.$$

For momentum and energy, the effect of the Lorentz transform is:
$$δH = -·,\quad δ = -M.$$
This is true both relativistically and non-relativistically, provided that $H$ is interpreted as kinetic energy. However, in relativity, the mass $M$ is now subject to Einstein's famous equation $E = Mc^2$, and this includes the rest mass $m$ plus a contribution from the kinetic energy $H/c^2$, so that you can write
$$M = m + \frac{H}{c^2}\quad⇒\quad E = mc^2 + H.$$
Since $m$ is invariant, then the effect of the Lorentz transform on $E$ is:
$$δE = δ\left(H + mc^2\right) = δH = -·.$$
For completeness, you can also write the following transforms:
$$δM = δ\left(\frac{E}{c^2}\right) = -\frac{·}{c^2},\quad δm = 0.$$

That means $(,E)$ forms a self-contained set under transform:
$$δ = -M = -\frac{E}{c^2},\quad δE = -·.$$
From this, you can derive the following:
$$\begin{align}
δ\left(·d - E dt\right)
&= δ·d + ·δ(d) - δE dt - E δ(dt)\\
&= \left(-\frac{E}{c^2}\right)·d + ·(- dt) - (-·) dt - E \left(-\frac{·d}{c^2}\right)\\
&= -\frac{E·d}{c^2} - · dt + · dt + \frac{E·d}{c^2}\\
&= 0.
\end{align}$$
So
$$·d - E dt$$
is an invariant.

You can also derive the following:
$$δ\frac{||^2c^2 - E^2}2 = ·δ c^2 - E δE = ·\left(-\frac{E}{c^2}\right)c^2 - E (-·) = 0.$$
Thus,
$$||^2c^2 - E^2$$
is an invariant.

So, I guess the answer to your question #1 is - because $E = Mc^2$.

If you had used $H$ in place of $E$, and worked out the math, then you would have found the following as the invariants:
$$||^2 - 2MH + \frac{H^2}{c^2} = ||^2 - 2mH - \frac{H^2}{c^2},\quad M - \frac{H}{c^2} = m.$$

By comparison, the non-relativistic versions of all of this is the following transform (the Galilei transform), similarly given in infinitesimal form:
$$δ(d) = - dt,\quad δ(dt) = 0,$$
and
$$δ = - M,\quad δH = -·,\quad δM = 0,\quad δm = 0.$$
The corresponding invariants are:
$$||^2 - 2MH = ||^2 - 2mH,\quad M = m.$$

As to *what* the invariant $||^2 c^2 - E^2$ is, since it is independent of frame of reference, then you go to the rest frame where $ = $ and $E = mc^2$. Then it becomes:
$$||^2 c^2 - E^2 = 0^2c^2 - \left(mc^2\right)^2 = -\left(mc^2\right)^2.$$

For Relativity, the transform properties for $$ and $E$ are equivalent to the requirement that $·d - E dt$ be invariant. In fact, had you started out by *assuming* it to be an invariant (and you can almost see a version of that cropping up in the middle of your derivation), then from this, you would have derived the following:
$$\begin{align}
0
&= δ(·d - E dt)\\
&= δ·d + ·δ(d) - δE dt - E δ(dt)\\
&= δ·d + ·(- dt) - δE dt - E (-\frac{·d}{c^2})\\
&= \left(δ + \frac{E}{c^2}\right)·d - (δE + ·) dt.
\end{align}$$
Separating the components $d$ and $dt$, you would end up with:
$$δ + \frac{E}{c^2} = ,\quad δE + · = 0,$$
or just:
$$δ = -\frac{E}{c^2},\quad δE = -·.$$

If you write this with $M$ in place of $E$ then you get:
$$δ = -M,\quad δM = -\frac{·}{c^2}.$$
So, $(,M)$ has the very same Lorentz tranform as $(d,dt)$. Since the finite form of the Lorentz transform - with a velocity $v$ in the $x$-direction - is:
$$dt → γ\left(dt - \frac{v dx}{c^2}\right),\quad dx → γ(dx - v dt),\quad dy → dy,\quad dz → dz,$$
then the corresponding finite form of the Lorentz transform for $ = \left(p_x, p_y, p_z\right)$ and $M$ is:
$$M → γ\left(M - \frac{v p_x}{c^2}\right),\quad p_x → γ\left(p_x - v M\right),\quad p_y → p_y,\quad p_z → p_z.$$

So, if you transform in reverse *from* the rest frame $(,M) = (,m)$, with $-v$ in place of $v$, then you'll get:
$$M = γ\left(m + \frac{v 0}{c^2}\right) = γm,\quad p_x = γ\left(0 + v m\right) = γmv,\quad p_y = 0,\quad p_z = 0,$$
or just $(M,) = (γm,γm)$, after generalizing the velocity to an arbitrary direction. From this, you obtain $E = Mc^2 = γmc^2$.

That was your question #3.

In your question #2, you already have $ = E/c^2$, so the rest follows from the invariant $||^2 c^2 - E^2 = -\left(mc^2\right)^2$, after substituting in for $$ and solving for $E$. But, we already by-passed the need for all of that above, and got the relations more directly, without any discussion about any relations to frequency or wave number.

Now, all of this sorta leaves a loose end dangling: what's the non-relativistic version of the $·d - E dt$ invariant, since that seems to be the actual lynch-pin of everything? If you try the same derivation with $·d - H dt$ - the relativistic version first - you'll end up getting:
$$\begin{align}
δ(·d - H dt)
&= δ·d + ·δ(d) - δH dt - H δdt\\
&= (-M)·d + ·(- dt) - (-·) dt - H \left(-\frac{·}{c^2}\right)\\
&= -\left(M - \frac{H}{c^2}\right) ·d\\
&= m(-·d).
\end{align}$$
For the non-relativistic version, you'll get exactly the same thing. The temptation is very strong to **force** it to be an invariant by just arbitrarily sticking in another coordinate $u$ with the following transform
$$δ(du) = ·d.$$
Then, what you'll find is that
$$·d - H dt + m du$$
is an invariant - *both* relativistically and non-relativistically.

With the extra coordinate $u$, you can also write down the following as invariants in place of $|d|^2 - c^2 dt^2$:
$$|d|^2 + 2 dt du + \frac{du^2}{c^2},\quad ds = dt + \frac{du}{c^2},$$
and their non-relativistic form:
$$|d|^2 + 2 dt du,\quad ds = dt.$$

You can try working out the finite forms of the transforms for each of these - both relativistically and non-relativistically - to see what arises.

They may not be ready for that yet, but their kids are going to love it.